# Ошибка генератора ('numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index')

Tags: python, numpy, keras

Написал свой генератор для `Keras`, X_data имеет тип сlass 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix', а y_data - class 'numpy.ndarray'
 но получаю ошибку на выходе:

```
def batch_generator(X_data, y_data, batch_size):
    samples_per_epoch = X_data.shape[0]
    number_of_batches = samples_per_epoch/batch_size
    counter=0
    index = np.arange(np.shape(y_data)[0])
    while 1:
        index_batch = index[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]
        X_batch = X_data[index_batch,:].toarray()
        y_batch = y_data[y_data.index[index_batch]]
        counter += 1
        yield X_batch,y_batch
        if (counter > number_of_batches):
            counter=0
```

Ошибка в строке:

```
y_batch = y_data[y_data.index[index_batch]]
```

Текст ошибки:

> ```
> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка:

> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

указывает на то, что `y_data` является `numpy.ndarray`.

У `numpy.ndarray`, в отличие от Pandas DataFrame/Series отсутствует атрибут `index`.

Попробуйте так:

```
y_batch = y_data[index_batch]
```

Comment: теперь 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @Midnight, укажите в вопросе типы переменных, которые подаются на вход функции

Comment: добавил тип в вопрос

Comment: @Midnight, я исправил ответ - так работает?

Comment: заработало, только не понимаю почему после определенного момента точность сети становится Nan

Comment: @Midnight, `"только не понимаю почему после определенного момента точность сети становится Nan"` - это уже совершенно другой вопрос. Можете задать новый вопрос и привести в нем небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных и ваш код...